# reduce function in hadoop doesn't work

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I learning hadoop. I wrote simple program in Java. Program have to counts words (and creates file with words and number of times each word appears), but program only creates a file with all words, and number "1" near every word. It's look like :

- rmd 1
- rmd 1
- rmd 1
- rmd 1
- rmdaxsxgb 1

But I want :

- rmd 4
- rmdaxsxgb 1

As I understood, works only map function. (I tried to comment reduce function, and have the same result).

My code (it is a typical example, of mapreduce program; it can be easily finded in internet or books about hadoop):

```
public class WordCount {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
 } 

 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    } }
```

I use hadoop on amazon web services, and don't understand why it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of the mix and match of the APIs. There are 2 APIs for hadoop the older being `mapred` and latest being `mapreduce`.

In  the latest API, the reducer handles the values as an `Iterable` compared to `Iterator` (old API) as in your code.

Try -

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable value:values) {
            sum += value.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it, and this helped, but there should be  `Iterable<IntWritable> values`,  you have a misprint.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that there is no reducer running in your hadoop cluster.
You can set it in three ways. You can either set it in your mapred-site.xml. set the property like

```
<property>
 <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
 <value>1</value>
</property>
```

OR by setting it in command line like

```
 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=1
```

OR by defining it in your main class

```
  job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```

To set it permanently for all jobs, you should set the property in your mapred-site.xml.